# Angular 2 weekday Pipe

Tags: angular

I want to use the date pipe in angular 2. but I need this output: Wednesday.

I know I can get this.

```
{{ strDate | date :'fullDate' }}
```

Output will be: Monday, November 7, 2016.

but I don't want the year.

or this.

```
{{ strDate | date :'longDate'}}
```

Output will be: November 7, 2016,

also, don't want the year.

how can I get just the weekday or November 7.

Comment: {{ strDate | date :'EEEE'}}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html)

It describes that you can define your desired output string by using an ISO string. In your case, the following entry should have the output you desire:

`{{ strDate | date :'EEEE'}} -> Saturday`

`{{ strDate | date :'MMMM d'}} -> May 20`

Comment: My requirement was: Thu 23 Oct . i did `{{ strDate | date : 'EE d LLL'}}`